# C# - Multiple filtering conditions

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
if (!UserIsInRole("Owners"))
    RegisterControlRule("CreatorID", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);
```

Notice the code is being filtered by `CreatorID`and this works in my case.

Now I would like to add another parameter `delegeatedToId`

I have tried the following

```
if (!UserIsInRole("Owners"))
    This is skipped >>> RegisterControlRule("CreatorID", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);
    This will runs  >>> RegisterControlRule("delegeatedToId", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);
```

But only the second filter is considered.

I also tried the following (just a silly idea)

```
RegisterControlRule("CreatorID","delegeatedToId", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);
```

**Additional Information:**

Guys, here is the wrapping

```
protected override void EnumerateAccessControlRules(string controllerName)
{
    base.EnumerateAccessControlRules(controllerName); 
    if (!UserIsInRole("Administrators"))
    {
        RegisterControlRule("InstanceID", AccessPermission.Allow, OrganizationID);
        RegisterControlRule("RoleID", AccessPermission.Deny, 1);

        // let's filter by created by if user is not the owner //CreatedBy
        if (!UserIsInRole("Owners"))
            RegisterControlRule("CreatorID", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);

       //Second filter 
            RegisterControlRule("delegeatedToId", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping both statements into curly braces?

Comment: HI @kalexi Yes I tried that too.. in vain

Comment: Could you update your example then to reflect this? How exactly did you do it?

Comment: For the second snippet, what is the actual, compilable code (not pseudocode) you tried?  Also, what library/assembly/framework is `RegisterControlRule()` from?  Is it possible multiple calls to `RegisterControlRule()` aren't cumulative?  That is, each call overwrites any rules from previous calls for a given ID?

Comment: @Yosh It's very, very important to show *exactly how* you wrapped them both in curly braces. I suspect that what you mean by that phrase may not be what kalexi had in mind, but if you show us the curly brace version of your code, we'll all be on the same page. Adding curly braces to code isn't like adding salt to your soup: It's not just a matter of how many, it's also where you put them.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have added additional information

Comment: @kalexi I have added extra information

Comment: @Yosh Thanks! Did you want both `RegisterControlRule` lines after `if (!UserIsInRole("Owners"))` to happen only if the user is **not** in the "Owners" role? Or do you want `RegisterControlRule("delegeatedToId",...` to happen every time, whether the user is in the "Owners" role or not?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I basically want to put an OR between CreatedID and DelegeatedToId..that was if a record is delegated to user_A,  user_A can still access that record. I hope this makes sense

Comment: @Yosh I'm sorry, but that doesn't make any sense at all. I don't know what `RegisterControlRule()` does and I have no way of finding out.

Comment: @Yosh https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s3p1.html here is a tutorial on conditional logic that i think could help you understand your if, else and else if statements better if youve never seen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `C#`, an `if` statement can exist with or without accompanying curly braces, but there's a difference.

```
if(a == b)
    a++;
    b++;
```

In the above, `a++` will occur only if the condition is true while `b++` will occur regardless, because only the line immediately after `if` is considered to be the thing to do if the condition is `true`.

On the other hand, using curly braces gets rid of the confusion and make things clear.

```
if(a == b)
{
    a++;
}
b++;
```

This code is equivalent to the above, but much less ambiguous.

In your case, the second register happens regardless of the outcome of the `if` condition, so I bet the second one overwrites the first one in the case your condition is `true`.

### EDIT

Even after your edited post, it's still not clear what your expected behavior is. When the `if` condition evaluates to `true` (i.e., if the user is *not* in the role 'Owners'), do you want both 'register' operations to happen, or only the first?

If you want both registers to happen if the condition is true, use it like this:

```
if (!UserIsInRole("Owners"))
{
    RegisterControlRule("CreatorID", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);
    RegisterControlRule("delegeatedToId", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);
}
```

If you want only the first one to happen, it would be like this, but bear in mind that in this case the second one will happen regardless of the outcome of the `if` condition.

```
if (!UserIsInRole("Owners"))
{
    RegisterControlRule("CreatorID", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);
}
RegisterControlRule("delegeatedToId", AccessPermission.Allow, UserId);
```

Also you haven't told us what this `RegisterControlRule` is or what its behavior is. Check the library's documentation and see if registering one rule overwrites the previous. In that case, in either of those above samples, only the last rule will remain registered.